# How can I access a local folder inside a WPF project to load and store files?

Tags: c#, wpf, filepath, solution, storing-data

I need a library of vector files, where the same files have to be used every time. I want to load them from a folder and have the option to store new ones.

I tried having a library folder inside the WPF project that contains the files:
`Solution/Project/Library/file1.dxf`
 I load them like this:

```
string currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
var cutOff = currentDir.LastIndexOf(@"\bin\");
var folder = currentDir.Substring(0, cutOff) + @"\Library\";

string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.dxf");
```

This worked when running on the PC the project was buid, but the program crashes when the .exe is run on another PC. How do I fix this or is there a better approach to this?

Comment: You do not need any of that.... All you need is the name of the folder.  Make sure you create the folder inside the "CurrentDirectory".  When the application runs there is no "bin" folder... so everything would be in the same folder as the .exe.... unless you specifically made it so that it is inside a subfolder

Comment: Be aware that an application may not have write access to its install location folder, so the previous comment may be useless. You would typically create and use a subfolder under `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` or `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData`.

Comment: If you would not need to save any data in that folder, it would be sufficient to set the `Build Action` of the file(s) in your Visual Studio project to `Content` and `Copy to Output Directory` to something else than `Do not copy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a subfolder under `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`, read the files in the library folder if it exists. If not create it and save the existing library files to it (here from resources):

```
string appFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string path = appFolder + @"\MyAppLibrary\";

if (!Directory.Exists(path))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

    // Add existing files to that folder
    var rm = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager;
    var resSet = rm.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
    foreach (var res in resSet)
    {
        var entry = ((DictionaryEntry)res);
        var name = (string)entry.Key;
        var file = (byte[])rm.GetObject(name);

        var filePath = path + name + ".dxf";
        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, file);
    }
}

// Load all files from the library folder
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dxf");
```

Thanks [Jonathan Alfaro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2495728/jonathan-alfaro) and [Clemens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1136211/clemens)!